# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in false

Tags: javascript, jquery

P.S-I know this has been asked. But the answers are too complicated for me to comprehend, besides I'm a newbie in JavaScript/jQuery 2.1.4.

Whenever I start my web app project, this error occurs. But the thing about this error is that it didn't stop the function from executing so it's good. Anyway I don't want to see this error, because I want my app to be error free; so I traced it up and here is my code:

```
//populate locations select options
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({           
        type: "GET",
        url: "asset_management/poploc", //the script to call to get data          
        data:'',                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
        dataType: 'json',               //data format      
        success: function(data){        //on recieve of reply
          $.each(data, function(index,item){
                $("#pop_loc").append("<option value=\""+item.location_id+"\">"+item.location_name+"</option>");
               });
        }

    });
});
```

Kindly check please.

Comment: Most likely, your `data` response is neither an object nor an array. Check the actual response in debugger/Network inspector.

Comment: what is the jQuery version ? could you add the JSON in your post ?

Comment: @Hacketo jQuery 2.1.4 and the JSON that i don't know how to check it out?

Comment: You have the HTTP response in the network tab of your browser, what do you got if you do `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @Hacketo the answer below solved my problem. But anyways in the console it displays 'false'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because on a text string, it `$.each` doesn't work. You need to parse the `data` as a JSON:

```
success: function(data) {
  // Add this following line.
  data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Also you can get rid of:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Make sure you give a validation before `$.each()`:

```
success: function(data) {
  // Add this following line.
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  // validate here
  if (data.length > 0) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` jQuery should already handle the JSON parsing

Comment: @Hacketo Most of the time, in my personal experience, adding `dataType: 'json'` and in the server side `Content-type: application/json` fails ultimately. I don't know the reason. Just showing the right way. That's all! `:P`

Comment: server side `Content-type` does not matter if you specified `dataType`. I guess JSON sended by the server is not JSON. Never failed for me

Comment: can u simplify by what u mean of validate? add example please

Comment: If it weren't a JSON response it would have triggered `fail` handlers on the jqXHR. I feel like the response is `false` which is a valid JSON for `false`.

Comment: ok when I added the if() statement the error was gone. Thanks :)

Comment: @treblaluch It is just for a safety check, whether you are receiving any inputs. Ha ha.